# How to get 0 to 180 degree in onSensorChanged

Tags: android, android-layout

```
x = (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[1], 2);
```

From this code i get only values from 0-90 but i want 0-180 right to left 
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For get Angle from Sensor,
You have to use `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` & `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`:

Check this [Code of angle from sensor](http://capycoding.blogspot.in/2012/10/get-angle-from-sensor-in-android.html), I hope it will work for you